# regexp to replace string after third '-' in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to replace a string only after 3 occurences of '-'.
Can someone give me a pattern for it?

ex: xxyy-xxyy-xxyy-xxyy where xx can be more than one character or number and I need to replace the last set of characters.

```
finalString = String.replace(/xx$/m, "z")
```

and this doesn't work because I don't know the last set of characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: That is for vim, will the regex in that answer work for Javascript as well?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: Vim regex != Javascript Regex

Comment: @anubhava Ohh I missed it.  I have retracted my close votes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
finalString = String.replace(/xx([^-]+)$/m, "z$1")
```

Comment: Thanks and again, it's almost there. it replaces everything after the last '-' but I need //=> xxyy-xxyy-xxyy-fooyy

Comment: No, I will try to explain me better. After the last '-' there will be a set of characters. I know that will start by 'xx' (this is what I want to replace) but after there will be more characters that I want to remain there and I don't know which characters are. Is it clear?

Comment: @JayJay: Ok, I see. Have a try with my modified answer, it'll replace last `xx` by `z`, keeping the rest unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var s = 'xxyy-xxyy-xxyy-xxyy';
var r = s.replace(/^((?:[^-]*-){3}).*/, '$1foo');
//=> xxyy-xxyy-xxyy-foo
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. This is almost perfect but I don't want to replace the whole set of characters just the XX part. //=> xxyy-xxyy-xxyy-fooyy

Comment: Another tip: this should search for the 'xx' after the last '-' (last '-' or third '-' because I that the string will only have 3 '-').

Answer (score 0):

This is something i took from `anubhava's` answer,  hope this is what you required

```
var s = 'xxyy-xxyy-xxyy-xxyy';
var r = s.replace(/^((?:[^-]*-){3})xx*/, '$1foo');
```

Comment: Athough this question is already answered I confirm that this solution works as well. Thanks.